# System default voice doesn't change on `say` command within tmux sessions

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

Recently I've changed my default system voice via "System Preferences > Dictation & Speech > Text to Speech > System Voice". If I open a new Terminal window and use the `say` command, the correct voice is used. However, the previous voice is still used if I use the `say` command within a tmux session.

I've tried restarting, shutting down tmux completely, and opening an entirely new tmux session with `tmux new-session -s foobar` and still it doesn't pick up the new preferred voice.

This is really a minor issue, but it eats at me that I have no idea why it's happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the same root cause as [that other issue](https://superuser.com/questions/231130/unable-to-use-pbcopy-while-in-tmux-session): many tools that need to interact with the UI (graphics, sounds...) fail within a tmux session: `say`, `pbcopy/pbpaste`, `nohup`, `launchctl export|getenv|setenv`, `subl` (Sublime Text command line tool), Retina rendering of apps launched under tmux, tools trying to access KeyChain (`curl`, `ssh`...), etc.

I remember GNU `screen` used to have the same problem but Apple patched it and now it works fine, but `tmux` still has the problem.

### Solution (2017-05)

Borrowing from answers in linked issue, for `tmux` you can do this if you have Homebrew:

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then put the following in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l $SHELL"
```

I reproduced your issue on macOS 10.11.4, and the above fixed it.

[See here](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) for more info on the nature of the problem, and its workaround (using undocumented macOS APIs)

### Better solution soon?

As mentioned in comment, future versions of tmux might do this dance natively, at least [it's being worked on, and current master has the fix](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/78352fdd328b611d935ba051288191b33278cc4a).

Comment: FYI, tmux got a recent commit that provides a native version of namespace attachment:

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/78352fdd328b611d935ba051288191b33278cc4a

Comment: @atomicstack Quite interesting, thanks! Added to answer :)